# Extend Document object in TypeScript 3

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

When I used TS 2 in my project the following worked just fine.

I have an interface that extends Document:

```
//To avoid TypeScript errors when using experimental functions
export interface ExtendedDocument extends Document {
    msExitFullscreen?: any;
    mozCancelFullScreen?: any;
    msFullscreenElement?:any;
    mozFullScreenElement?: any;
  }
```

And this interface that extends HTMLBody:

```
//To avoid TypeScript errors when using experimental functions
export interface ExtendedHTMLBodyElement extends HTMLBodyElement {
    mozRequestFullScreen?: any;
    msRequestFullscreen?: any;
  }
```

So that I can use the browser-specific experimental features without errors:

```
        const htmlDocument: ExtendedDocument = document;
        const elem: ExtendedHTMLBodyElement = htmlDocument.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
if (!htmlDocument.fullscreenElement && !htmlDocument.webkitFullscreenElement && !htmlDocument.msFullscreenElement && !htmlDocument.mozFullScreenElement) {
            if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
                elem.requestFullscreen();
            }
            else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) { /* Firefox */
                elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
            }
            else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE11 */
                elem.msRequestFullscreen();
            }
            else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Chrome */
                elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
            }
        }
```

I updated to TS 3.2 and now when I build my project it throws these errors:
[image]

What has changed in TS and what do I have to change in my code for this to compile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In current TS version `fullscreenElement` does not exist in `Document` type. So if you sure that `fullscreenElement` will not throw error you can add it to `ExtendedDocument` interface definition.

e.g.

```js
export interface ExtendedHTMLBodyElement extends HTMLBodyElement {
   ...,
   fullscreenElement: ...
}
```